# Javascript .multiply 'function cannot be found'

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, class-method

I am playing around with trekhleb's javascript-algorithms repo - specifically the Fast Fourier Transformation. The code can be found here:

https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/blob/master/src/algorithms/math/fourier-transform/fastFourierTransform.js

I am looking to understand line 57:

```
const component = output[signalId + blockLength / 2].multiply(phase);
```

When I debug this, the operation trying to be executed is: float.multiply(object).

When I run this I get 'multiply is not a function'. And this makes sense as the float is not a object of the ComplexNumber class which contains a .multiply method.

Comment: it's a method  from  import ComplexNumber

Comment: Yeah I know there is a method there, but 'output' isn't a complexNumber object so it can't be called on it.

Comment: this is a chaining, not a call

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I just understand why the execution is throwing the error

Comment: I have read up on the principles of promise chaining and method chaining, I still  just do not understand how it applies here